# Override compass sprite images per theme with the default fallback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprite, compass-sass

Given the file structure similar to:

```
- themes  
|---+ default
    |- a.png
    |- b.png
    \- c.png
 ---+ foo
    \- a.png
 ---+ boo
    \- b.png
```

Meaning that the directory `app/assets/images/themes/default` contains 3 files. The other 2 themes (foo and boo) "override" some of those files.

I need to generate sprites for each of the theme taking into account the images that are replaced for that particular theme.

For example:

- the sprite for theme `default` should contain 3 files: `default/a.png`, `default/b.png`, `default/c.png`
- the sprite for theme `foo` should contain: `foo/a.png`, `default/b.png`, `default/c.png`
- the sprite for theme `boo` should contain: `default/a.png`, `boo/b.png`, `default/c.png`

How can I achieve this using [Compass spriting](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/)?

(Using Rails 4)

Comment: They mention how to do this right on the page you linked. Look at the nested folders section.

Comment: @JustinWood no, not really. They don't mention how to "fallback" to other folders if one of the files is missing there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution today.
But an issue exists: https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1286